# Why do we use superscript notation and asterisks when describing bootstrap samples?

Tags: bootstrap, notation

I'm currently reading 'An Introduction to
Statistical Learning' and I'm trying to grasp bootstrapping.  I am wondering why a superscript * and number value are used to describe a bootstrapped data set, ie.,

"We randomly select n
observations from the data set in order to produce a bootstrap data set, $ Z^{*1}$"

1. Where does this naming convention come from?
2. Is subscript *n (ie., $Z_{*4}$) ever used?

edit:

An image of the notation from ISLR:
[image: example of bootstrap superscript]

Comment: The asterisks are used to distinguish the first actual observation $X_1$ from the first drawn bootstrap observation $X_1^*$. As a reader and student of bootstrap and also an author of bootstrap books I have never used or seen the forms of notation that you describe.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks for the clarification, I think this is an idiosyncrasy of this book and some other materials I have been looking at.  If it's not a widespread notation, I would prefer to not use it.

Comment: The example you show is a little different from what I was saying.  I was talking about the indices for observation in an individual bootstrap sample. The b is indexing the complete bootstrap samples.

Comment: @MichaelChernick ok, so am I correct in understanding that the superscript *b denotes the bth bootstrapped sample, whereas the subscript indicates a single observation from the bootstrapped sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a way to indicate "this is a bootstrap resample, not the original data".

   As a result, we might use a symbol to indicate "this is resampled". The asterisk ($^*$) is commonly used for that. Sometimes you will see two used when the bootstrap samples are in turn resampled.
2. Since there are many bootstrap samples, you need a way to indicate which one you're referring to.

   For example, if you want to write how to compute some statistic across samples, you need some way to indicate the $k$-th bootstrap sample (say). Since we already have a subscript (to denote the $i$-th observation in a sample), it makes sense to use a superscript.

The notation you refer to does both those necessary things. I've seen that particular notation used quite a few times though several other notations are also used.